# css hover an element without affecting :after

Tags: css, pseudo-element

How do I stop an pseudo element from being affected by parents hover?

```css
.list-item {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.list-item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.list-item:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: orange;
  z-index: 10;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-item">
  test
</div>
```

When hovering it applies all hover effects to :after pseudo element

Comment: Use the :not() selector: You can use the :not() selector to target the parent element and exclude the pseudo-element from the hover state. For example, you can change the .list-item:hover rule to .list-item:hover:not(:after).

```
.list-item:hover:not(:after) {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

```

Comment: @RomJanD.Hossain That doesn't work. `::after` is a pseudo-class and is bound to follow the transform of the parent.

Answer (score -1):

One method can be to apply an opposing transition to the `::after` pseudo element:

```css
.list-item:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

.list-item:hover::after {
    /* transform: scale(calc(1 - (your main scale amount - 1) / 2)); */
    transform: scale(0.75);
}
```

Comment: this would trigger an animation where the pseudo would grow/shrink rapidly plus I would like to add more features like filter drop-shadow etc...

Comment: I don't understand the formula for the scale - what would happen if the main scale amount was, say, 3?

Comment: @MortenS. I doubt there is any other way to achieve what you are trying to do.